# Can I do this - token=str.split(" "||",");

Tags: java, regex, split

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class TrimTest{
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
String[] token = new String[0];
String opcode;
String strLine="";
String str="";
    try{
        // Open and read the file
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("a.txt");

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));

        //Read file line by line and storing data in the form of tokens
        if((strLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            token = strLine.split(" ");// split w.r.t spaces 
                            token = strLine.split(" "||",")   // split if there is a space or comma encountered
            }
        in.close();//Close the input stream
    }
    catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    int i;
    int n = token.length;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        System.out.println(token[i]);
        }
}
}
```

If the input  MOVE R1,R2,R3
Split with respect to space or comma and save it into and array token[]
I want output as:
MOVE
R1
R2
R3

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You cannot use a boolean operator like || inside a regular expression to get the intended output.

Comment: String.split takes a regex as its sole parameter.  Make a regex that matches a space or a comma.

Comment: @gansai: Wrong. Look at the [Logical Operators in JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: @jlordo: I had meant || being used here. || is used to operate on operands for true or false in java.

Comment: @gansai: You are right, the double pipe `||` won't work in a regex. The single pipe `|` also is a boolean operator and does indeed work in a regex.

Comment: @jlordo: I think in the context of regex, we need not call | a boolean operator, since a boolean operator primarily operates on truth values. ( '0, 1' OR 'true,false' on operands which can be boolean operands. Here in regex, the intention is to tell whether it can match a pattern as of the form a OR b when we say a|b. If in this context, we consider | to be a boolean operator, then a and b needs to be boolean operands and they need to have truth values and I assume as part of a regex we dont intend to focus on truth values.

Comment: @gansai: The regex `a|b` matches (=true) for `a` **or** `b` ;)

Comment: @jlordo: I totally agree with the above comment. :)

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 1):

Try `token = strLine.split(" |,")`.

`split` uses regex as argument and `or` in regex is `|`. You can also use [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like `[\\s,]` which is equal to `\\s|,` and means `\\s` = any white space (like normal space, tab, new line mark) OR comma".

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
token = strLine.split("[ ,]"); // split if there is a space or comma encountered
```

Square brackets denote a character class. This class contains a space and a comma and the regex will match on any character of the character class.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to `strLine.split(" |,")`, or maybe even `strLine.split("\\s+|,")`.

Comment: token = strLine.split(" |,");
When I do this the array is saving some of null values. How can I make a condition so that it doesnt saves null values into token[]?